# How to programmatically map OneDrive for business?

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, cookies, webdav, onedrive

Mapping OneDrive for business as a network location requires authentication via MicrosoftOnline.com login form.
In our ADFS setup user only needs to type in a username - no password- and check "Stay logged in" to successfully 
authenticate.

Location *domain-my.sharepoint.com@SSL/DavWWWRoot/personal/username_domain/* can then be mapped and will remain on the current computer until IE cookies are cleared. These cookies contain multiple hashed keys and cannot be manually created.

Naturally we find the need of user having to

- Open a browser
- Navigate to the login form
- Type the username you just entered

quite a nuisance, especially when these cookies granting our access need to be received on every machine and 
our users change their workstations on a **daily basis**.

I've come up with an approach of automating IE but it's rather hackish, with simulated keypresses and all, and therefore not certain enough. Now you might be asking, why not just use the official OneDrive client MS provides? It forces synchronization, something we don't want.

I'd like to know if there's any method of requesting these cookies  programmatically

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to programmatically map a network drive to OneDrive (or OneDrive for Business) is with a commercial tool like WebDrive. You can create a site profile that keeps the credentials stored (encrypted) in the registry. If you go to the WebDrive online help file http://www.webdrive.com/support/webdrive/v12/ and go to the “Advanced Topics” section there is a subtopic called “Automating Connections.” This describes the few quick steps to do this.

You may also want to look at the  sections on scripting and command line parameters, also under the “Advanced Topics” section.

BTW, this will map as an actual network drive rather than a network location.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485450/map-onedrive-for-business-as-a-drive-letter-dirsync-with-adfs/

Basically create ADFS smart links, enable auto logon and script (hidden) IE open, navigate and close in a login script.

Map the drive with GP Preferences.

Users should logon to their workstations with their Office 365 credentials (email), then when the Office 365 sites are trusted and IE is configured to automatically logon with username and password users won't have to type anything at all.

ADFS Smart links: http://www.messageops.com/creating-ad-fs-smart-links-for-transparent-sso-experience/

Comment: The answer you've referenced at the beginning of this answer is gone. (Looks like the question it was on has been deleted.) Can you possibly repost it here?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Drive Mapper from IAM Cloud works really well for many users. This allows drive letters to be used for ODFB and SPO libraries. It works for customers using ADFS or native O365 authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with programmatically setting up a mapped network drive via WebDAV with the Windows WebClient service is that it relies on cookies from Internet Explorer to authenticate with Office 365 OneDrive for Business. Therefore automating this process requires automating Internet Explorer to perform the authentication.

There are Powershell scripts and programs created by the community that can help you do this either by automating Internet Explorer or creating the IE cookie directly:

- [office365drivemap.codeplex.com](http://office365drivemap.codeplex.com/)
- [www.lieben.nu/numb3rs/?page_id=129](http://www.lieben.nu/numb3rs/?page_id=129)
- [fabiocuneaz.blogspot.it](http://fabiocuneaz.blogspot.it/)

Or you could try a commercial tool like Zee Drive that authenticates directly to OneDrive for Business and comes with its own mapped drive provider so it is not reliant on Internet Explorer or cookies: [try mapping network drives to OneDrive for Business and team site libraries with Zee Drive](http://www.thinkscape.com/Map-Network-Drives-To-Office-365-OneDrive/)

Disclosure: Zee Drive is a tool that my organisation develops.

Comment: My only reason for rejecting ZeeDrive was that it would actually cost us more in monthly subscriptions to Zeedrive than we pay as an Enterprise for Office365 as a whole suite. I really can't see the ability to bypass one login page worth thousands of dollars in annual subscriptions.